# How to call html code in a function

Tags: html

I am developing a tab in my website and I want to have html code for different tab in different file.how do I call html code from one file to another

Comment: Does the tab have to be dynamically generated? Or can it be loaded at the same time the rest of the page loads?

Answer (score 0):

Four options; Ajax, dynamic JavaScript, tab already loaded with display:none;, or iframe.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this to do what i think you need.

```
(function () {
    var UI;
    UI = {
        main: function () {
            var elems;
            elems = "<div id='div1'>Div 1</div>";
            elems += "<div id='div2'>Div 2</div>";
            body.innerHTML = elems;
        }
    }
    window.onload = function () {
        UI.main();
    }
}());
```

note: body.innerHTML goes to the ID, not the tag.  So HTML would look just like this:

```
<body id='body'>--JS inception here--</body>
```

So if you are going to target a specific tab, it would look like this:

```
elems = "<div>my tab</div>";
myID.innerHTML = elems;
```